# Spinner setSelection data is going to vanish when scrolling ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-spinner

Hi I am new for android and in my ListView,I have added Spinner.

I am facing problem,when I have selected any item from spinner and,I scroll my ListView.
Spinner setSelection data is being vanished.

Please help me how can I resolve this problem ?

### MainActivity:-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ArrayList<Friend> friendArrayList;

    String[] countriessArray =  { "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA",
            "China", "Japan", "France", "USA","USA", "USA", "USA", "USA",
            "China", "Japan", "France", "USA"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

        friendArrayList = new ArrayList<Friend>();
        for (int i = 0; i < countriessArray.length; i++) {

            Friend item = new Friend(countriessArray[i]);
            friendArrayList.add(item);
        }

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        ListViewAdapter adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, R.layout.item_listview, friendArrayList);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

### ListViewAdapter:-

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Friend> implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    private List<Friend> myFriends;
    private Activity activity;
    private int selectedPosition = -1;

    public ListViewAdapter(Activity context, int resource, List<Friend> objects){

        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.activity = context;
        this.myFriends = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        // If holder not exist then locate all view from UI file.
        if (convertView == null) {
            // inflate UI from XML file
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_listview, parent, false);
            // get all UI view
            holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            // set tag for holder
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            // if holder created, get tag from view
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.checkBox.setTag(position); // This line is important.
        holder.friendName.setText(getItem(position).getName());

        if (position == selectedPosition) {
            holder.checkBox.setChecked(true);
        } else holder.checkBox.setChecked(false);
        holder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(onStateChangedListener(holder.checkBox, position));

        // Spinner Drop down elements

        List<String> categories = new ArrayList<String>();
        categories.add("Automobile");
        categories.add("Business Services");
        categories.add("Computers");
        categories.add("Education");
        categories.add("Personal");
        categories.add("Travel");

        // Creating adapter for spinner
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(activity, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categories);

        // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        // attaching data adapter to spinner
        holder.spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

        holder.spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // On selecting a spinner item
    }
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    private View.OnClickListener onStateChangedListener(final CheckBox checkBox, final int position) {
        return new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
                    selectedPosition = position;
                } else {
                    selectedPosition = -1;
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {

        private TextView friendName;
        private CheckBox checkBox;
        private Spinner spinner;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {

            checkBox = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.check);
            friendName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
            spinner = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.spinnerList);
        }
    }
}
```

### Friend:-

```
public class Friend {

    private String name;

    public Friend(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better way to do is..
Add selection as property in your Pojo class of Friend.

Like: 
int selection = 0;
Add getter setter.

And in your OnItemselected,set its value to the selected position of spinner.
and in your getview,you need to add condition and fetch value from its getter method.

Change your classes to below:

```
public class Friend {

    private String name;
    private int selection = 0;

    public Friend(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

   public void setSelection(int selection) {
        this.selection = selection;
    }

    public int getSelection() {
        return selection;
    }
}
```

And in your adapter view,

Change this holder.spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
to this :

```
holder.spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                getItem(position).setselection(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });;
```

And in your getView after listener,
add

```
try {
        holder.spinner.setSelection((getItem(viewpos)).getSelection(),false);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
```

Comment: i am very new for android please provide solution with code

Comment: can u provide me solution?

Comment: if(getItem(position).getselection() != null)
{
    holder.spinner.setSelection(getItem(position).setselection(position));
}

Comment: Logcat please..
I have manually written it,so it might have some issue..
Provide logcat lines of error..

Comment: no no i did not run when i paste this below code in getView after listener,
if(getItem(position).getselection() != null) { holder.spinner.setSelection(getItem(position).setselection(position)); }

Comment: setSelection (int) in AbsSpinner can not be applied

Comment: what error?
hover your cursor over it..it will show the error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109783/discussion-between-krish-and-aditi-parikh).

Comment: `getItem(position).setselection(position);` -- this doesn't work for me, as the object returned from `getitem` is not a `spinner` object.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal because every time you are scrolling getView is called to get the cell's view and in there you are resetting the spinner items.

holder.spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
this line (and the ones that initialize the dataAdapter and set the click listener) should be placed inside the if (convertView == null) block (this is where the cell view is initialized).

In onSpinnerClick method you should keep track of the selected item for each cell and before returning the convertView you should set holder.spinner.setSelectedItem() so that each cell's spinner will show the previously selected item

Comment: i am very new for android please provide solution with code and i can easily do this please help me